# I can't seem to see data from my database. I tried putting up data inside announcement table

Tags: sql

Query not producing a result:

```
 SELECT AnnouncementID,
 Announcement, Date_Posted, Employee.EmployeeID , 
 Employee.AccessLevel
 FROM Announcement
 INNER JOIN Employee on Announcement.AnnouncementID = Employee.EmployeeID;
```

[EmployeeTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YRSg.png)

[Announcement Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgBcr.png)

Comment: Does this query run without an error? what are your tables like etc?

Comment: This query runs but theres no data when i run it.

Comment: Have you got examples of your tables and its data?? what happens if you select * from Announcement or select * from Employee

Comment: It wil show announcemet ID, announcement, dateposted and employee id

Comment: is there data in there? can you screenshot the tables for me?

Comment: @RyanGadsdon i edited the question. Please check

Comment: ok, and what does the employee table look like as well?

Comment: @RyanGadsdon edited sir

Comment: What is the table structure for your announcement table and the select * query for your employee table

Answer (score 0):

At the current moment without seeing your employee table if you use this query it should return a result

```
  SELECT AnnouncementID,
  Announcement, Date_Posted, Employee.EmployeeID , 
  Employee.AccessLevel
  FROM Announcement
  LEFT JOIN Employee on Announcement.AnnouncementID = Employee.EmployeeID;
```

You need something along the lines of this

```
 ALTER TABLE Employee
 ADD EmployeeFK int;


 ALTER TABLE Employee
 ADD FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeFK) REFERENCES Announcement(AnnouncementId);
```

Here is a very basic example of what you need but i advise you need to read up on foreign keys.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/261e20/1

The announcementFK is a foreign key in the employee table that is linked to the announcementid in the announcement table. You can then join on these values.

e.g. the value is 1 in the announcement table and the value is 1 in the employee table so therefore these match and a result is returned. Sorry but its hard to explain over the internet...

Comment: [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI9jh.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nref.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dHbl.png 
I tried the query and this are the results. i want to see the data for access level but i cant get it

Comment: Ok, i understand now. The reason your inner join query is not working is because you have no foreign key in your employee table. You need to add a foreign key to the employee table that references the announcement id in the announcement table. Once you have done this you can then join them and you will get the result you want

Comment: Bare with me and i will try and create a demo for you

Comment: @NicoD Was this of any help?

Comment: @NicoD if this was of help can you please upvote and tick my answer thanks :)